# An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Dependencies"

Tags: eclipse, dependencies

Whenever I run eclipse, I get the message:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Dependencies".
Lorg/codehaus/plexus/archiver/jar/JarArchiver;
```

I am running maven version 3.0.4, and I've tried to update the JarArchiver only for it to fail time and time again.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing the problem?
If you have a solution, that would also be incredibly helpful.

Comment: Have you checked that the Maven inside eclipse can read from central?

Comment: Err, I attempted to, I think. I don't think it is though as when I tried to update all dependencies it gave the error: Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'eyespy'.
Lorg/codehaus/plexus/archiver/jar/JarArchiver;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After closing Eclipse I removed all versions from `~/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver` except for the latest.

During the subsequent Eclipse startup another artifact causing an error was Maven Archiver, so I deleted old versions from `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver` as well.

After another Eclipse restart I performed Maven -> Update Project. All was well after that.

Comment: Apparently it works for all instances... seems I had the same problem with the IO jars somewhere... meh, thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Steps below worked for me to resovle the issue(Add the following in pom.xml)

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
 </plugin>
```

Reimport the project again in Eclipse/STS.

The plugin configuration is taken from the maven site below:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: as for me, in june 2016, added the jar-plugin version 3.0.0 and i got rid of the error

Answer (score 3):

The answer from user2125483 did not work for me.  I tried selectively removing `org.maven` and `org.codehaus.plexus` package subdirectories of my local Maven repository (`~/.m2`) without any change in the error message.  I needed to nuke my entire local Maven repository and rebuild from nothing for this error to vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the repository in the ./m2 worked for me

Comment: This is a duplicate of [an answer posted above a year before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17279209/1240557)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above solutions but the error didn't go away. So then I checked Installed Programs on my windows machine and found two different versions of Java installed. (9.0.4 and 10.0.0)
I removed Java 10 and now Maven update works. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error occured when trying to import and build an older project with a JDK 11. I switched back to JDK 8 and it seems to work now.

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus and delete all the subfolders inside plexus and re-run the pom.xml file

!! it worked !!

Comment: This essentially repeats what's already in the long-accepted answer.