# Error converting dynamic web project to Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

While trying to convert dynamic web project to Maven project i get the error:

**An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/jar/JarArchiver**

I am using Eclipse Kepler IDE for Java EE Developers.

I tried the solutions mentioned in this link [An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Dependencies"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491298/an-internal-error-occurred-during-updating-maven-dependencies) , but didn't work for me.

Any idea what should be done to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you pls place screenshot or stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the error by choosing the **Packaging** as **jar** , while converting to Maven Project . I earlier selected the packaging as war , which created the issue.

Answer (score 0):

need to update forcefully the maven Right click on the project -> then go to maven -> update the project - select force to update

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).